# Getting Unmet dependencies error while installing or removing application from ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dependencies

Unable to install new app or remove existing app from ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

OS Type => 32-bit

i've tried to install skypreforlinux 64 Bit, Now unable to remove this incomplete installation

```
sudo apt-get purge teamviewer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libnl-3-200 : Breaks: network-manager (< 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.3~) but 0.9.8.8-0ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
 skypeforlinux:amd64 : Depends: libasound2:amd64 (>= 1.0.16)
                   Depends: libatk1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.12.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcairo2:amd64 (>= 1.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libcups2:amd64 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libexpat1:amd64 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libfreetype6:amd64 (>= 2.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgcc1:amd64 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgconf-2-4:amd64 (>= 3.2.5) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.31.8) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.24.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libnspr4:amd64 (>= 2:4.9-2~) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libnss3:amd64 (>= 2:3.13.4-2~) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libpango-1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libpangocairo-1.0-0:amd64 (>= 1.14.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libsecret-1-0:amd64 (>= 0.7) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libv4l-0:amd64 (>= 0.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libx11-6:amd64 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libx11-xcb1:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcb1:amd64 (>= 1.6) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcomposite1:amd64 (>= 1:0.3-1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxcursor1:amd64 (> 1.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxdamage1:amd64 (>= 1:1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxext6:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxfixes3:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxi6:amd64 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxrandr2:amd64 (>= 2:1.2.99.3) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxrender1:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxss1:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libxtst6:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: apt-transport-https:amd64 but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libfontconfig1:amd64 (>= 2.11.0) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libdbus-1-3:amd64 (>= 1.6.18) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libstdc++6:amd64 (>= 4.8.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

i've following skype installed on my mahine

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep 'skype'
skype                       install
skypeforlinux               install
```

Output in terminal is in this screenthot: [Outout Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwmI7.png)

Comment: Please try to uninstall the  `skypeforlinux:amd64` package. If it doesn't work, please edit your question to include the complete output.

Comment: I've tried dpkg --get-selections | grep 'skype'

and i've skype & skypeforlinux in output

when i try to remove any of them i get same error as above in question.

Comment: What happens if you run "apt-get install -f"?

Comment: @davidbaumann i gett follwoing error:

Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skypeforlinux:amd64 : Depends: libasound2:amd64 (>= 1.0.16) ... E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Comment: And if you run "apt remove --purge skypeforlinux:amd64" now?

Comment: thanks @davidbaumann i've manually installed libnl-3-200 for i386 then i removed skypeforlinux:amd64 and my "Dependencies Unmet" errors are resolved now